# Code needed for form to talk to phpmyadmin backend

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms, phpmyadmin

I am creating a search form in wordpress using html and javascript. The form has dropdown menus which will have preselected items. These items come from the phpmyadmin(wordpress backend database). I'm having trouble writing the php code so the form talks to phpmyadmin backend. Does anyone have code for this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This site functions most effectively when questions are phrased to help programmers overcome reproducible, code-related challenges.  In that spirit, please post the code you've written, along with any errors or obstacles you've encountered.  See the following link for community guidelines on asking questions- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is *not* your database. MySQL is. phpMyAdmin is just a tool to make managing your database easier. That's a very basic fundamental distinction that you should know *before* you start working with databases.

Comment: Given that you're working with Wordpress, there's plenty of info here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: the code has too many characters to post here

Answer (score 0):

John is right on that. PHP MyAdmin is a web based utility for accessing MySQL similar to WordPress which is a CMS. You will need to make queries to the backend database either directly(Not Advised) or to a web server. Wordpress has support for plugin databases built right in. Just gotta do a couple things.

**Per The WordPress Site**

1. Write a PHP function that creates the table.
2. Ensure that WordPress calls the function when the plugin is activated.
3. Create an upgrade function, if a new version of your plugin needs to have a different table structure.

[WordPress - Creating Tables with Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins)

---

If you insist on writing it yourself you will need to setup a web server like Apache or nginx to listen to request and execute your PHP scripts.

[PHP 5 Form Handling](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

[PHP Connect to MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

and if you want to go dynamic

[Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) and [JS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp), but you may want to use [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/) for testing.